How to detect the location of a hump in a signal?
I have a signal which looks like this:

There is a hump in the signal, with some noise, and I need to identify the location of the hump. The hump is created electromagnetically, so it can be weaker than in the example image: if the source is getting further away, the hump is smaller and smaller, while the base "carrier" only diminishes in magnitude by very little.
Finding a peak, even after some filtering, is not a good option, for two reasons.

as the hump gets weaker and weaker as the source gets further away, the chance increases that some noise will get picked as a peak. The signal might sometimes be somewhat noisier than in the image above. We should only get a position if we are sure it's a wide enough hump, otherwise we must determine that there is no hump at all.
the hump might not be symmetrical, even in the original example the peak is not in its center. But consider the following two cases, where the same position should be detected, but the peaks give two very different locations:


I already implemented a method, which works fine for most of the cases, but still has issues.
My approach:
I know for sure that the hump cannot start sooner than about the first tick on the x axis in the original example, and by that time the "carrier" has already stabilized. I sample the signal there (several measurements, averaged), to build a reference, then use the reference * 1.5 as a threshold for detecting the rising and falling edges of the hump, with a small hysteresis between the two thresholds to avoid potential noises during the rising edge.
Then I can even say that no hump was present, if these thresholds are never reached.
This works for the most part, but the hump must be very well defined for it to work reliably.
Here is an example from an oscilloscope measurement (the original example was constructed out of ADC measurements inside the device which has to evaluate the signal)

Yes, some variants can have two humps, but that's not the issue, they are just two signals in succession, and I can evaluate them individually. We can see that the emitter of the signal is physically approaching the detector. Different emitters have the humps at different positions, this is what we need to distinguish. The green impulses just show that the hump was successfully detected.
We can see, that with our human eyes we can confidently detect the humps during the 4th signal, but my method only detects it in the 9th.
If I zoom in the 4th and 5th signals, it is less obvious:

We can see now that the threshold-based approach cannot reliably work here. If I don't detect the 4th (first in the zoomed in image), it's still not a problem, it's better to discard it than to get a false position. But I'd like to detect the next one at least, but it's easy to see that the threshold approach is not the best.
If I can obviously and unambiguously detect them with my human eyes on the zoomed out oscilloscope image, then surely an algorithm could detect it as well.
My idea would be to detect something akin to a center of mass, by first normalizing the signal to its average (as in, taking the average to be zero on the y axis). Or, as it would be best to detect it during one single pass, normalizing it to the reference measured near the beginning. I'm not sure if this is the right approach, or if there are established methods to detect such a "center of mass".

The more you know about the signal and the background, the more reliably you can detect it. Examples are

Width of a hump
Spacing between events
Properties of the background is signal. Is it mostly constant or does it drift. If it drifts, how fast.

From look at the picture, I would try the following 2 stage approach.

Split the signal into individual events at the "zero dips"
Run your existing "obvious" hump detection algorithm first.
If that's negative: Model the background. I think just using the mean would work, but there is drift you can model it as a line (with a slope) using a polynomial fit.
Subtract the background model.
Run a moving average filter with a length of the as a hump width. Put a threshold detector on the output of that filter
If you don't know the width an alternative (after step 4) would be to identify all segments that are consecutively positive and detect based on the minimum length of a segment and the average height.


if there are established methods

Not really. The best methods for detection a weak signal in a  noisy environment depend a lot on what information is available and that's different for each application.
